# Weblogic server is not listed in server list in eclipse even after installing the plugin

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I have installed the following plugin http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/juno

and restarted eclipse,but still the web logic servers are not listed in the server list.please suggest.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using with Eclipse? The Oracle plugin has a minimum JDK requirement in order to work properly.

Comment: JDK version is 1.7..

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of OEPE requires JDK 1.8 and Eclipse Luna.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/system-requirements-101778.html